# TTF - reading glyph data

Tags: truetype

I'm working on implementing true type fonts in my program but there is a huge problem interpreting some data to the correct values from the glyph table.

I'm working with the windows specification (Link: https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.html)
and in addition the apple specification (Link:
https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6glyf.html)

And in order to check the values I'm using this page:
(Link: https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html)

The font that I'm using is the raleway font - medium

(Link: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/raleway)

I can see that the values of numberOfContours, xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax and endpContour[0] are correct so far. I don't know about the instructionLength[0].

The example below is not the general code but the bytecode for the entry that I need to interpret correctly. 
The problem is that I can't get my head around the next values to fill. (instructionLength, flags...) 
The character that is represented below is the acute. It is made of 4 points.

The expected result of the 4 points from that only one contour are: 
p0: x=106, y=609 
p1: x=48, y=629 
p2: x=106, y=730 
p3: x=194, y=730
additional information: 
advanceWidth: 232 
leftSideBearing: 48 
(source: https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html)

In sum the arcute consists out of 50 bytes.

```
1.      0   | -> 0000 0000 | -> 1       | -> 0000 0000 0000 0001 | (ind. 0) <- numberOfContours
2.      1   | -> 0000 0001 | ^
3.      0   | -> 0000 0000 | -> 48      | -> 0000 0000 0011 0000 | (ind. 1) <- xMin
4.      48  | -> 0011 0000 | ^
5.      2   | -> 0000 0010 | -> 609     | -> 0000 0010 0110 0001 | (ind. 2) <- yMin
6.      97  | -> 0110 0001 | ^
7.      0   | -> 0000 0000 | -> 609     | -> 0000 0000 1100 0010 | (ind. 3) <- xMax
8.      194 | -> 1100 0010 | ^
9.      2   | -> 0000 0010 | -> 730     | -> 0000 0010 1101 1010 | (ind. 4) <- yMax
10.     218 | -> 1101 1010 | ^
11.     0   | -> 0000 0000 | -> 3   | -> 0000 0000 0000 0011 | (ind. 5) <- endpContour[0]
12.     3   | -> 0000 0011 | ^
13.     0   | -> 0000 0000 | -> 23  | -> 0000 0000 0001 0111 | (ind. 6) <- instructionLength[0]
14.     23  | -> 0001 0111
15.     177 | -> 1011 0001 
16.     6   | -> 0000 0110 
17.     100 | -> 0110 0100
18.     68  | -> 0100 0100
19.     64  | -> 0100 0000
20.     12  | -> 0000 1100
21.     1   | -> 0000 0001
22.     1   | -> 0000 0001
23.     0   | -> 0000 0000
24.     71  | -> 0100 0111
25.     0   | -> 0000 0000
26.     0   | -> 0000 0000
27.     0   | -> 0000 0000
28.     116 | -> 0111 0100
29.     18  | -> 0001 0010
30.     1   | -> 0000 0001
31.     9   | -> 0000 1001
32.     21  | -> 0001 0101
33.     43  | -> 0010 1011
34.     177 | -> 1011 0001
35.     6   | -> 0000 0110
36.     0   | -> 0000 0000
37.     68  | -> 0100 0100
38.     19  | -> 0001 0011
39.     39  | -> 0010 0111
40.     55  | -> 0011 0111
41.     51  | -> 0011 0011
42.     106 | -> 0110 1010
43.     58  | -> 0011 1010
44.     58  | -> 0011 1010
45.     88  | -> 0101 1000
46.     2   | -> 0000 0010
47.     97  | -> 0110 0001
48.     20  | -> 0001 0100
49.     101 | -> 0110 0101 
50.     0   | -> 0000 0000
```

I need to know from you how the get the instructionLegths and it's values correct and what it is used for (couldn't find something about that in the docs.) the flags and the points I mentioned above.

Thank you in advance!